# How to make unordered list in html inline

Tags: html, css

I am trying to create a row of images using unordered list.
But when I try to make the list inline, it isn't working.
What is the error here?

```css
#first-list ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#first-style li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-list">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="13.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="6.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: @AliMustafa it isn't working

Comment: Your CSS rule targets `#first-style` but the ID is `first-list`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry `display: inline` should be written in li. The problem you are facing is because of the #first-style you are using before the ul and li. Remove it. Also if you have more than one unordered lists then you have to specify like this:  `#first-list ul` and  `#first-list li` otherwise the ul and li will apply to all lists generally.

```css
ul{
        padding: 0;
        list-style: none;
        margin: 0;
        
    }
    
li{
       display: inline; 
    }
```

```html
<div id="first-list">
            <ul>
                <li><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="13.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="5.jpg"></li>
                <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="6.jpg"></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
```

Comment: This will style all li elements and all unordered lists rather than only those in that containing div.

Comment: Obviously, it will, if he has more than one unordered list.

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct apart from using #first-style to select the correct li elements.

The id of the containing div you are interested in is first-list.

```css
#first-list ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#first-list li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-list">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="13.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="6.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if you misspelled you code in the `css`. All you need to do is to change `#first-style` to `#first-list`. This is because when you write  the id of `first-style`, it is refering to the `first-style` wrapper, which you don't have in the code provided. Also, due to the fact that you wanted to make the `#first-list` element inline, that is why you must find the `li` in the `#first-list` rather than the `first-style`. Below is a code demonstration:

```css
#first-list ul {
  padding: 0;
  list-style: none;
  margin: 0;
}

#first-list li {
  display: inline;
}
```

```html
<div id="first-list">
  <ul>
    <li><img src="images/13.jpg" alt="13.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="2.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="3.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/4.jpg" alt="4.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="5.jpg"></li>
    <li><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="6.jpg"></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: I misspelt it while copying it here.